# A property referencing another property in a PowerShell Class

Tags: class, powershell, object

Is it possible to have a property in a class reference another?  For example, something like this.  I've tried a few ways and I'm now not sure if I can do this...:

```
class TestClass {

    [string]
    $SQLInstanceName

    [string]
    $Server = "$($env:COMPUTERNAME)\$SQLInstanceName"

    [string]myResult()
    {
        return $this.Server
    }
}
```

....Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Here it is implemented in your class definition:

```
class TestClass {

    [string]
    $SQLInstanceName

    hidden $_Server = $($this | Add-Member ScriptProperty 'Server' `
        {
            # get
            "$($env:COMPUTERNAME)\$($this.SQLInstanceName)"
        }
    )

    [string]myResult()
    {
        return $this.Server
    }
}
```

To see this working, new up an instance and assign a value to `SQLInstanceName`.

```
$c = [TestClass]::new()
$c.SQLInstanceName = 'MyDB'
```

Then invoking

```
$c.Server
$c.myResult()
```

results in

```
ComputerName\MyDB
ComputerName\MyDB
```

Comment: Thanks.  This has shown me a few new things and dynamically changes the Server.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `$this` if you want to refer to a non-static property/method in the same object just like you have done with your `myResult()` method. Also your current sample has no default value or constructor so the SQLInstanceName is blank so just adding `$this`, without setting the variable, might give you misleading results. The following example might be something to consider but it is flawed.

```
class TestClass {

    [string]$SQLInstanceName = "Test"

    [string]$Server = "$($env:COMPUTERNAME)\$($this.SQLInstanceName)"

    [string]myResult()
    {
        return $this.Server
    }
}

$tcobject = New-Object TestClass
$tcobject.myResult()
```

However this does not work if you *change* the SQLInstanceName property since you are just setting default values. Classes in v5 don't really have get and set truly implemented in the same way as a .Net class so you would have to roll your own solution for that as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39717230/powershell-class-implement-get-set-property)  but also on [this blog](https://xainey.github.io/2016/powershell-classes-and-concepts/#accessorsmutators-aka-gettersetter) about v5 classes in general.

So a *simple* solution would work like this to get what I think you want.

```
class TestClass {

    [string]
    $SQLInstanceName = "Test"

    [string]
    $Server = $env:COMPUTERNAME

    [string]myResult()
    {
        return "$($this.Server)\$($this.SQLInstanceName)"
    }
}

$tcobject = New-Object TestClass
$tcobject.SQLInstanceName = "server\prod"
$tcobject.myResult()
```

This would be a design choice but I would not be trying to dynamically change one property based on the value of another *in this case*. Since you are using a value of them combined a simple method could work.

Comment: Thanks Matt.  Also especially for explanations and the link to the Blog.  Looks good. Cheers.